# Why does UIImageView show image tiny compared to Safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a simple custom cell with a UIImageView loading a picture from the Internet as follows

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"shopifyCell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 NSDictionary *dict = [_shopifyCollections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 // Configure the cell...
 //[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"description"]]];

 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
 NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

 return cell;
```

The problem is that it shows up extremely tiny ( about 0.5cmx0.5cm ), but if I open the same link in safari on the same iPhone it shows up in much larger size.

I tried resize the UIImage in the storyboard and also to adjust the auto layout constraints but it had no effect so I must be missing something here.

How can I control the size of the UIImageView in my custom cell to make it the size I want which is more similar to the web view of the same image?

EDIT ***

I tried adding the contentMode as follows but nothing changes

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
 NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

EDIT 2 ***

fixing some mistakes with not mapping the correct cell, this now works horizontally but not vertically, why can I now scale it in the X direction but not in Y direction?

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"]];
 NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 cell.shopifyCellMainImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 cell.shopifyCellMainImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Use the UIViewContentMode property.

Comment: Ok but how exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example how to adjust table cells to images. The idea is to preload images and to use their heights to calculate exact cells height in `tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. Also we use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` to get correct results.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewController {

    IBOutlet UITableView *_tableView;

    CGFloat _imgViewWidth;

    NSArray *_urls;
    NSMutableArray<UIImage *> *_images;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _urls = @[@"http://gzsihai.com/data/out/180/im-502387394.jpg",
              @"http://s.chzbgr.com/s/unversioned/images/square_logos/PictureIsUnrelated.png",
              @"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/794708906094317572/Bb8lpZ2t.jpg"];
    _images = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (NSString *urlStr in _urls) {
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
        NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [_images addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    }

    TableViewCell *cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(TableViewCell.class) owner:self options:nil][0];
    _imgViewWidth = cell.imgView.frame.size.width;

    [_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _urls.count;
}

- (TableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"reuseIdentifier";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imgView.image = _images[indexPath.row];
    cell.imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat imgWidth = _images[indexPath.row].size.width;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = (imgWidth < _imgViewWidth) ? 1. : _imgViewWidth / imgWidth;

    return _images[indexPath.row].size.height * scaleFactor;
}

@end
```